# Date functions in temporal tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

Since SQL Server 2016 it is possible to automatically create Temporal Tables. I wanted to create a simple query that retrieves the data from a specified date. However, when I try to specify a date in the query like so, it gives a syntax error:

```
SELECT * FROM Person FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF GETDATE()
```

I even tried to convert the datatype to a datetime2, since the dates a stored like that, but it still wouldn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM Person FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF CONVERT(datetime2,GETDATE())
```

This problem occurrs, but when I first execute `SELECT GETDATE()` and then copy the text and paste it into the query, it works fine.
How can I specify a datetime with the AS OF keyword?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME2 = GETUTCDATE()

SELECT * 
FROM Person
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @Date
```

Also, take a look at [this article](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-query-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-tables-in-sql-server/) for more examples of querying temporal tables.

Comment: Wow, I cannot for the life of me understand how that works. Now I'm curious.

Comment: Well, it seems it cannot handle a function call on the condition. The same happens if you have a stored procedure and want to call it with `GETDATE()` as param, you will also need this workaround: assign `GETDATE()` to a local variable and pass that as a param instead of the `GETDATE()` function call.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables), the `SYSTEM_TIME` is determined by the UTC time of the system clock. So might be worth declaring the variable `DECLARE @Date DATETIME = GETUTCDATE()`, as the difference in time zones may make a difference on the query results.